# Swapped Halogen bulbs to LED without bypassing the ballast

Tags: led, halogen

I Swapped Halogen bulbs to LED without bypassing the ballast, which I  later found out i was supposed to do.

The LED's did not work and when I placed the halogen bulbs back into the sockets, only one out of 3 now works.

The light bulbs are 13w 4 Pin 827 (2700k) G24q-1

What is the problem and how to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about 12V halogen bulbs here?

Comment: Please take the tour so you know how to use this site.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: You may have damaged the LED's. You  may have damaged the ballast. We need much more info on the products you have. Halogen and LED model numbers.

Comment: What did you use for LED bulbs?